# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, nginx, websocket, content-security-policy

I use WebSocket `(wss://)` in my local server and it's work fine with :

- invalid SSL (i used kubernate and ssl is required for this)
- no Reverse Proxy (Nginx)

but when deployed this program into server that configed nginx as reverse proxy and valid ssl (certbor, let's encrypt) my program is not working and getting this error in java script clent and some detail i write there:

**Error Browser Console:**

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
> resource at ws:/// (“default-src”).

**Java Script Code that error point to:**

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://' + location.host + '/<some-url>');
```

**Nginx Config:**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

   include /etc/nginx/conf-enabled/*.conf;
   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;


    server {
          listen       443;
          listen [::]:443 ;

          server_name  www.<my-domain> <my-domain>;

          location / {
            proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:<my-port>/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          }

          ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my-domain>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
          ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my-domain>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
          include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
          ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 points:

1. You have CSP headers issued somewhere by production server. Spring Security does not add Content Security Policy by default, Nginx can do so, by I do not see something like: `add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'";` in its config.
   Anyway, check [servlet-headers-csp](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-headers-csp) is it has like that:

`@EnableWebSecurity`
`public class WebSecurityConfig extends`
`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {`

`@Override`
    `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {`
        `http`
            `.headers(headers -> headers`
                `.contentSecurityPolicy(csp -> csp`
                    `.policyDirectives("default-src 'self'")`
                `)`
            `);`
    `}`
`}`

or:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'");
    }
}
```

make sure `'self'` is there or add `ws:` to existing rules. On https: pages `'self'` is insidious - it allows https: and wss: only (not http: and ws: - anyway these will blocked as mixed content). On http: pages 'self' allows https: / wss: / http: / ws:.
  May be is better to add specific `connect-src 'self'` or `connect-src ws://site.com wss:site.com` directive to your CSP.
  If you do not need CSP, just remove relevant:

```
http.headers()
  .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'");
```

2. In err: `blocked the loading of a resource at ws:///` - the ws:/// means that in `new WebSocket('wss://' + location.host + '/<some-url>')` `location.host` is empty, so websocket have no where to connect. Any CSP will block `ws:///` source as invalid.

Comment: thanks for your response, but first solution dont load my js files  nd get me an  error(i don't check it with wss), second is not my point, location.host is <my-domain>

Comment: First solution - is to find where is your server publish CSP header. And if you not familiar with CSP or do not need it - just switch it off. If you just add second CSP header - yes it will break JS/CSS.

Comment: how can i disable CSP? this is in server side?

Comment: CSP can pe published 2 ways: via HTTP header (it's always server side); via meta tag `<meta http-equiv=Content-Security-Policy content="CSP rules here">` (commonly server side, but as any meta tag it can be setted by script in client side). In para 1. of answer I showed examples of code to search in server side in Spring congif. In the Nginx config it could be somethng like that `add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"`. You do not use meta tag for CSP because on Dev you did not have problems. Therefore - server side.

Comment: Thanks. therefore i add in client side: <meta http-equiv=Content-Security-Policy content="CSP rules here"> to page that contains wss:// js file (top than wss://) and add header  "Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'";" for server side ?

Comment: 1. No: OR `<meta Content-Security-Policy>` OR header "Content-Security-Policy", not both (2 CSPs simultaneously affects with each other). 2. You already have somewhere CSP published on server side. Find it and remove or modify(add `ws:` `wss:`) if you need CSP

Comment: thank u for your reply, i solved this by adding header into NGINX.